# Is this a permutation thing or something else?

Tags: c#

for 1 set of exercises a person does 1 round
for 2 sets he/she does 2 rounds
for 3 sets he/she does 3 rounds
then back again to 2 sets and 2 rounds
and 1 set with 1 round

I looked up permutations but it doesn't take into account what's needed

```
using System;

namespace First_Application
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //reading input data
            string inputData = Console.ReadLine();
            int numberOfRounds = Convert.ToInt32(inputData);

            //formula for n rounds


            //display the result
            Console.WriteLine(numberOfRounds); 
        }
    }
}
```

The total number of rounds is 9. I need to code this so it works for any number.

Comment: What number do you enter? What should program do with it? What you have tried and why it didn't work?

Comment: This question seems to be [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)...